# What's the mechanism of `inserter` in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I tried the code blow, the `inserter` and `back_inserter` make the same `lst3`,but I think the `inserter` should produce a list of `{4,3,2,1}` as new element should be inserted to the location before `lst3.begin()`. Why do they make the same result?
Thanks!

```
int main() {
    list<int> lst = {1,2,3,4};
    list<int> lst3;
    // copy(lst.cbegin(), lst.cend(), inserter(lst3, lst3.begin()));
    copy(lst.cbegin(), lst.cend(), back_inserter(lst3));
    for_each(lst.cbegin(), lst.cend(), [] (const int i) {cout<<i<<endl;});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: add one element (let's say -1) to `lst3` before `std::copy`, then see what happens. `inserter(lst3, lst3.begin())` will give you `1 2 3 4 -1` and `back_inserter` `-1 1 2 3 4`

Comment: IIUC, the confusion is that it doesn't insert to `lst3.begin()` every time. cppreference explains that in the `inserter` example: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter

Answer (score 1):

> new element should be inserted to the location before lst3.begin()

You're imagining the equivalent of this:

```
 copy(lst.cbegin()+0, lst.cbegin()+1, inserter(lst3, lst3.begin()));
 copy(lst.cbegin()+1, lst.cbegin()+2, inserter(lst3, lst3.begin()));
 copy(lst.cbegin()+2, lst.cbegin()+3, inserter(lst3, lst3.begin()));
 copy(lst.cbegin()+3, lst.cbegin()+4, inserter(lst3, lst3.begin()));
```

*(pretending that those `+` operations would work on list iterators)*

I can see why you'd think that, but no.

When you provide `lst3.begin()` to `inserter`, this iterator isn't stored/cached and repeatedly used — we know that it can't be, because (thinking about the general case for a moment; lists specifically aren't prone to this) such an iterator might be invalidated by each insertion operation.

Instead, the iterator is incremented after each operation.

[cppreference explains this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter):

> when inserting in a sequence container, insertion point advances because each std::insert_iterator::operator= updates the target iterator

Indeed, we can see this for ourselves from [the cppreference `insert_iterator::operator=` page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator/operator%3D).

The end result is that you're actually inserting in a linear, left-to-right sequence, like:

```
 copy(lst.cbegin()+0, lst.cbegin()+1, inserter(lst3, lst3.begin()));
 copy(lst.cbegin()+1, lst.cbegin()+2, inserter(lst3, lst3.begin()+1));
 copy(lst.cbegin()+2, lst.cbegin()+3, inserter(lst3, lst3.begin()+2));
 copy(lst.cbegin()+3, lst.cbegin()+4, inserter(lst3, lst3.begin()+3));
```

*(pretending that those `+` operations would work on list iterators)*

This behaviour is actually more intuitive; the *entire* source range has been inserted, in its original order, at the position beginning `lst3.begin()`.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you're seeing is correct for [std::inserter()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter).

The behaviour you're expecting  - that is, *always* inserting at the front - is what you'd get using [std::front_inserter()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/front_inserter).

Answer (score 0):

@Lightness Races in Orbit's answer is correct.

In a nutshell, `std::inserter(container, iterator_argument)` always bind to that `iterator_argument` position initially passed in.

For example:

```
vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,4};
auto it = std::inserter(vec, vec.begin() + 1);
```

inside state:

```
1,2,3,4
  ↑
  it
```

insert an element:

```
*it = 888;
```

inside state:

```
1,888,2,3,4
      ↑
      it
```

insert an element:

```
*it = 999;
```

inside state:

```
1,888,999,2,3,4
          ↑
          it
```

So you **don't** get a reverse order sequence.

Btw, for a `std::inserter`, you just need to keep doing `*it = value` for inserting. And `it++` or `++it` has no effect on `std::inserter`. The position is bound forever.

---

Also check the doc:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator/operator=

> 1) Results in `iter = container->insert(iter, value); ++iter;`

So what's value of `container->insert(iter, value);`?

It's:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert

> 1-2) Iterator pointing to the inserted value

Answer (score -1):

The [`std::inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter) functions creates a [`std::insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator) object from the arguments that are passed to the functions.

The problem you experience is because of two things:

- The first is that the iterator is *copied*
- The second is that when a container is empty, its `begin` iterator is equal to its `end` iterator.

Therefore the `std::insert_iterator` object will have a copy of the lists `end` iterator and therefore insert at the end of the list.

Since you iterate from the beginning of the existing list, and always inserting at the end, the effect will be exactly the same as using `std::back_inserter` where the elements are inserted in the order they are iterated over.

Comment: Well, the elements are always inserted in original order, right? OP asks why they aren't inserted in reverse order, which is never happening.